# How to know if voltmeter in an electronic diagram connected to a resitance or not

Tags: electrical-resistance, electronics

Greeting.
Can someone please explain to me why the voltmeter in this diagram read zero?
The problem say beacuse it is not connected to a resistance but I don't know how to tell whether a voltmeter in a diagram is connected to a resistance or not. There are 2 resistor symbols, why the problem say the meter is not connected to a resistance ?
I know some formulas for electronic (for the asvab test), but I still can't read a diagram even after using books ('Asvab for dummy" and 'Mastering the asvab') and searching through Google.
And if it's an ammeter instead of voltmeter (symbol V is replaced by symbol A), what will the result be?
.[image]

Comment: Your question may be homework so I will only help, but look at the circuit wire to the right of the voltmeter. How do you think it will affect the meter?

Comment: Looks like the person who wrote the test question only has a weak understanding of the concepts. When they said, "the meter is not connected across a resistance," they probably were thinking that the meter _is_ "connected across" a zero Ohm wire, and that zero Ohms is "not a resistance." There's a kernel of truth in that, but it's stated in a clumsy, misleading way. An electrical engineer would not say that the meter was connected "across" anything. An EE would say that both of the meter's terminals are connected to the same [_circuit node_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(circuits)).

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, the two terminals of the voltmeter are connected by a wire:

[image]

And in lumped circuit analysis, we consider wires as equipotential regions.

So the voltmeter must read 0 V.

If you want to connect the voltmeter to measure the voltage across a resistor, you must connect one of its terminals on one side of the resistor, and the other terminal on the other side of the resistor, for example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. And Merry X-mas.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Distinguish the circuit [with ideal wires] from the ideal measurement devices
  by focusing on the circuit first [without the measuring instruments], then showing measurement devices as supplementary pieces [which I have redrawn, as shown].
- Color code equipotentials [as shown].

[image: robphy-circuit-intuition]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help✨. And happy holiday 